# Disabling printer default margin with css (with chrome)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, margins

With Adobe Indesign it's possible to get this result:

[image]

I tried to get the same result with css

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page 
{
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}

body 
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    border: solid 1px black ;
    margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the content before sending to   printer */
   }
</style>
```

but it's impossible to set the margins to 0. I always have a margin on the 4 sides:

[image]
I'm using google chrome to do my tests. I also tried:

[image]

same thing, some little white margins on the 4 sides...what's wrong?

Any help would be appreciate. JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L63dc1yd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I haven't seen the option 'US Letter bordeless' in the page size selection list. The css was OK, it override the chrome default margin setting.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this problem with [CSS3 Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

```
@media print {
    html,body {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank can you add a sample fiddle?

Comment: It's weird, on the print preview I have no margin but not on paper

Comment: @Frank did you tried set margin value under 0? like -5px

Comment: yes that does not work. I thought that it was specific to my printer (some security margins) but InDesign can print a sheet without these white margins.